# Wordpress theme with Gulp file structure

Tags: wordpress, gulp

I’m trying to develop a custom Wordpress starter theme with Gulp built in. Seems like the file structure of a Gulp project (with its src and dist folders) doesn’t jive with that of a Wordpress theme, which seems to want all the php files in the root directory of the theme.

Am I supposed to develop the theme outside of Wordpress, then move the contents of dist/ into wordpress/wp-content/themes/ after running the build task? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You CAN develop outside of on one localhost directory and then output the files into another directory, but it would complicate the process. It's better to work in the same directory, newly output file will replace the old one and that's about it.